# About passing dynamic simulation to load test setup

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I am using gatling-maven and need to pass the dynamic simulation for load test the scenario. Currently I am passing the users and duration to the scenario with the help of jvm args and it works fine for me. But need the way where i can pass the simulation dynamically which we pass into the setup, so that i don't need to touch the code again and again for different type of simulation. So is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

if i clearly understand you, you can set your simulation like this

`mvn gatling:test -Dgatling.simulationClass=%path to simulation%`